# User isnt getting remembered in Flutter Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication

so every time the App Process on my phone or emulator gets killed, the user in my app gets automatically to the LoginPage and must re-login.. it´s very time consuming to login everytime when you are restarting the app. The Firebase documentation says, that the user will get remembered but in my case it won´t...

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learnon/screens/about.dart';
import 'package:learnon/screens/schwarzesbrett.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:feedback/feedback.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import "./screens/selectionpage.dart";
import './screens/product_detail.dart';
import './providers/products.dart';
import '../screens/settings.dart';
import "../screens/essensplan.dart";
import '../screens/vertretungsplan.dart';
import '../screens/startscreen.dart';
import '../widgets/configtheme.dart';
import '../screens/auth_screen.dart';
import '../screens/reset.dart';
import '../screens/lehrerkürzel.dart';

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    "high_importance_channel", "High Importance Notifications",
    importance: Importance.high, playSound: true);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await Hive.initFlutter();

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => Products(),
      child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'LearnOn',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData.light(),
          darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
          themeMode: currentTheme.currentTheme(),
          home: LoginScreen(),
          routes: {
            ProductDetail.routeName: (ctx) => ProductDetail(),
            Settings.routeName: (ctx) => Settings(),
            WebViewContainer.routeName: (ctx) => WebViewContainer(),
            Essensplan.routeName: (ctx) => Essensplan(),
            StartScreen.routeName: (ctx) => StartScreen(),
            ForgotPassword.id: (context) => ForgotPassword(),
            SchwarzesBrett.routeName: (ctx) => SchwarzesBrett(),
            About.routeName: (ctx) => About(),
            Lehrerkuerzel.routeName: (ctx) => Lehrerkuerzel(),
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**auth_screen.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

import 'package:learnon/screens/bugstatus.dart';
import 'package:learnon/screens/startscreen.dart';
import '../screens/reset.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  // form key
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // editing controller
  final TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  //create box1
  late Box box1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createBox();
  }

  void createBox() async {
    box1 = await Hive.openBox("logindata");
    getdata();
  }

  void getdata() async {
    if (box1.get("emailController") != null) {
      emailController.text = box1.get("emailController");
    }
    if (box1.get("passwordController") != null) {
      passwordController.text = box1.get("passwordController");
    }
  }

  // firebase
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //storage key
  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

  // string for displaying the error Message
  String? errorMessage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //email field
    final emailField = TextFormField(
        autofocus: false,
        controller: emailController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        validator: (value) {
          if (value!.isEmpty) {
            return ("Bitte Email-Adresse eingeben");
          }
          // reg expression for email validation
          if (!RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z]")
              .hasMatch(value)) {
            return ("Bitte gültige Email-Adresse eingeben");
          }
          return null;
        },
        onSaved: (value) {
          emailController.text = value!;
        },
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
          hintText: "Email",
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
        ));

    //material buttons

    //password field
    final passwordField = TextFormField(
        autofocus: false,
        controller: passwordController,
        obscureText: true,
        validator: (value) {
          RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'^.{6,}$');
          if (value!.isEmpty) {
            return ("Bitte Passwort eingeben");
          }
          if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
            return ("Bitte korrektes Passwort eingeben(Min. 6 Zeichen)");
          }
        },
        onSaved: (value) {
          passwordController.text = value!;
        },
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
          hintText: "Passwort",
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
        ));

    //forget password

    final forgetPassword = Material(
        elevation: 5,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        color: Colors.green,
        child: MaterialButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(
                context,
                ForgotPassword.id,
              );
            },
            child: Text(
              "Passwort vergessen?",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )));

    //password remembering
    final Stream<User?> firebaseUserChanges =
        FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges();

    //login button

    final loginButton = Material(
      elevation: 5,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      color: Colors.green,
      child: MaterialButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          onPressed: () {
            signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
            login();
          },
          child: Text(
            "Login",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                        height: 200,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/Sgglogo_sw_white.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        )),
                    SizedBox(height: 45),
                    emailField,
                    SizedBox(height: 25),
                    passwordField,
                    SizedBox(height: 35),
                    loginButton,
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    forgetPassword,
                    SizedBox(height: 25),
                    Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => Bugstatus()));
                              },
                              child: const Text("Early Access App",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                  ))),
                        ])
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void login() {
    box1.put("emailController", emailController.text);
    box1.put("passwordController", passwordController.text);
  }

  // login function
  void signIn(String email, String password) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      try {
        await _auth
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
            .then((uid) => {
                  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Login erfolgreich!"),
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StartScreen())),
                });
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
        switch (error.code) {
          case "invalid-email":
            errorMessage = "Your email address appears to be malformed.";

            break;
          case "wrong-password":
            errorMessage = "Dein Passwort ist falsch.";
            break;
          case "user-not-found":
            errorMessage = "User mit dieser Email existiert nicht!";
            break;
          case "user-disabled":
            errorMessage = "User with this email has been disabled.";
            break;
          case "too-many-requests":
            errorMessage = "Zu viele Anfragen";
            break;
          case "operation-not-allowed":
            errorMessage = "Anmelden ist zurzeit nicht verfügbar";
            break;
          default:
            errorMessage = "Ein nicht definierter Fehler ist aufgetreten!";
        }
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: errorMessage!);
        print(error.code);
      }
    }
    }
  }
```